# How to deserialize a string with a variable classname

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I need to deserialize a JSON-string that holds a series of tables but one of the classes consists of only a string and does not hold a title. So I don't know how I can specify the class with just a string.

This is a simplified sample:

```
"tables" : {
    "tableId1" : {
      "name" : "Name_Of_The_Table"
      },
    "tableId2" : {
      "name" : "Name_Of_The_Table"
      },
    ...
    }
```

In reality there are about 100+ different tables with each individual names.

The classes I'm using to deserialize this are below:

```
public class jsonBaseClass
{
   public List<tableClass> tables {get; set;}
}

public class tableClass
{
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

So the issue I'm having is that I need to include the tableId also in the tableClass but I don't know how I can include this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sounds like your `tables` property should be a `Dictionary<string, tableClass>`. As an aside, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions - you can use `[JsonProperty("tables")]` etc to specify the name to use in JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON-string is coming from an external source, so I don't have any control over the format.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting changes to the JSON string at all. I was suggesting changes to your code.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: I've already said what to do: change `jsonBaseClass.tables` to be a `Dictionary<string, tableClass>`... and then fix the naming of all the types and properties to follow naming conventions, using `[JsonProperty("...")]` to specify what the expected name is in the JSON (so that it can be different from the name in the code).

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute to get the desired results as you want, here's a sample:**

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string data = @"{
            'tables' : {
                     'tableId1' : {
                            'name' : 'Name_Of_The_Table'
                    },
                    'tableId2' : {
                      'name' : 'Name_Of_The_Table'
                    }
            }
         }";

       RootObject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);

       Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
   [JsonProperty("tables")]
   public TableCollection Tables { get; set; }
}

public class TableCollection
{
   [JsonProperty("tableId1")]
   public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("tableId2")]
   public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table1
{
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

Outputting:

```
{
  "tables": {
    "tableId1": {
      "name": "Name_Of_The_Table"
    },
    "tableId2": {
      "name": "Name_Of_The_Table"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Alternatively, if the property names are unknown then use JSON.NET LINQ.**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string data = @"{
            'tables' : {
                     'tableId1' : {
                            'name' : 'Table1'
                    },
                    'tableId2' : {
                      'name' : 'Table2'
                    }
            }
         }";

        JObject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data);

        List<JObject> tableObjectList = deserializedObject["tables"]
                                .Cast<JProperty>()
                                .Select(x => x.Value)
                                .Cast<JObject>()
                                .ToList();

        List<string> tableIDList = deserializedObject["tables"]
                                .Cast<JProperty>()
                                .Select(x => x.Name)
                                .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tableObjectList, Formatting.Indented));

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tableIDList, Formatting.Indented));

    }
}
```

Outputting:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Table1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Table2"
  }
]
[
  "tableId1",
  "tableId2"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kunal, but this is a list with 100+ tables with different names, so I can't use a table collection as you suggested. I really need it to be a list with a way to convert the ID into a queryable object.

Comment: @Cainnech you want to extract the names in the inner table object ?

Comment: Well I need everything. I need the table object but I also need the ID with it. I don't know if there is a way for example to add the ID inside the tableclass?

Comment: @Cainnech which `ID(s)` ?

Comment: in the examples provided, it's tableId1 and tableId2